# update-grub fails on lvm cryptoroot

Tags: 12.04, grub2, raid, lvm, cryptsetup

Disclaimer: I'm running this server now but I did NOT install it.

I have two disks connected to an Intel Hardware Raid Controller running in RAID1. On top of it there is a fully encrypted 12.04 installed. When I run `update-grub2` I get the following error messages reapeatedly which prevents me from updating my Kernel:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-*-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-*-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
```

For each kernel I have installed it tries to generate a new entry for grub but it fails on the grub-probe command. I have already traced down the problem to the grub-mkconfig script in /usr/sbin/.

In line 132 it tries to get the device for / with the command `grub-probe --target=device /`. This returns:

```
/dev/mapper/server-root
```

In the next line the script tries to get the UUID for the previously found root device with `grub-probe --device /dev/mapper/server-root --target=fs_uuid`. This is where grub-probe throws the error:

```
grub-probe: error: no such disk.
```

In line 134 the script tries the same but for /boot instead for / and there the error appears the second time.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Here I provide some more information:

`bootinfoscript`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9331656/

`blkid`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9331960/

If you need more info I happily provide them.